# Inconsistent interaction between UISearchController and UINavigationController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I'm getting weird, random, inconsistent behavior from UISearchController interacting with a UINavigationController in iOS 8.  After selecting the search bar, sometimes iOS shows the view on the right and sometimes the one on the left:

[image: two different views]

You can see it [better illustrated in motion on YouTube](http://youtu.be/4G_Eic4KjNQ).

I don't care which version I get, but it's the inconsistency that's driving me crazy.

Here's the code for `viewDidLoad` where both the search bar and the toolbar are set up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create our 4 view-filter buttons & a flex space
    self.mainButton            = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Main"      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(viewMain)];
    self.viewedButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Viewed"    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(viewViewed)];
    self.favoritesButton       = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Favorites" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(viewFavorites)];
    self.allButton             = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"All"       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(viewAll)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    // Add toolbar buttons
    NSArray *rightSideButtons = @[self.mainButton, flexSpace, self.favoritesButton, flexSpace, self.viewedButton, flexSpace, self.allButton];
    [self setToolbarItems:rightSideButtons];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:FALSE animated:FALSE];

    // Set up search bar
    self.searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y,
                                                       self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    // this tells the search controller where to display
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

Any idea why iOS seems to randomly switch between showing the toolbar or covering it up with the keyboard?  Let me know if you need any more code, but I posted all the seemly relevant parts.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, FWIW, this is on iOS 8.1 and I see the same results on iPad and iPhone hardware as I do in the simulator.

Comment: That's a good observation.  I'm not using `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` or `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` anywhere in my code. Should I use them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing 2 things:

First, I removed the line `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:FALSE animated:FALSE];` from my `viewDidLoad` statement (as seen in the question).

Second, in my Storboard, I enabled the **Shows Toolbar** on the Navigation Controller containing the affected Table View:

[image: Metrics]

I think this changed the way that Xcode baked my UI, and so far I haven't seen the toolbar pushed up by the keyboard when invoking search.

At least, I hope that made the difference… otherwise it's probably voodoo. :-)